# Angularjs unit testing image.onload

Tags: javascript, angularjs, image, unit-testing, onload

I have the following angularjs service which I would like to unit test:

```
angular.module("services")
.factory("imageService", function($q)
{
    var load = function(options)
    {
        var deferred = $q.defer();
        var image = new Image();

        image.onload = function()
        {
            deferred.resolve(image.width);
        };
        image.src = options.imageSource;

        return deferred.promise;
    };

    return {
        load: load
    };
});
```

My unit test looks like this:

```
describe("imageService", function()
{
    beforeEach(module("services"));
    beforeEach(function()
    {
        inject(function($injector)
        {
            imageService = $injector.get("imageService");
        });
    });

    it("should return image width", function(done)
    {
        imageService.load({
            imageSource: "data:image/jpeg;base64,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"
        })
        .then(function(width)
        {
            expect(width).to.equal(2);
            done();
        });
    });
});
```

The problem I am having is that the onload call is asynchronous, and normally you would use `$timeout.flush()` after the call to flush the deferred task, but since it takes some time for the image to load, you cannot flush the task after you have called the function, and thus the `done()` function will never be called causing the test to fail.

Libraries used:

- angular 1.6.6
- angular-mocks 1.5.5
- karma 1.1.2
- karma-mocha 1.1.1
- karma-chai 0.1.0

Comment: Load would be through HTTP though.  Why flush `$timeout`?  Why not flush with [`$httpBackend.flush()`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngMock/service/$httpBackend#flushing-http-requests)?

Comment: Nope, I'm passing it a base64 data url string, as you see in the tests. flush is needed after calling deferred.resolve().

Comment: Right, but the browser still treats base64 images as data URI meaning it would probably get treated as a URL call, but resolve immediately.  I'll try to check that myself.

Comment: did not know that, would love to hear what you find out

Comment: Same problem with $httpBackend.flush(), "No pending request to flush !". I thought the delay had to do with loading the image inside the image object? If I just allow the tests to continue running and print out a console log when it resolves I can see in the console that it resolve about a second later.

Comment: Noone has a solution to this? :(